# PayPal Plus with payment wall, how do I generate an approval_url?

Tags: api, paypal

I'm about to integrate paypal plus iframed payment wall and about to documentation the initialization script looks as it follows

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
        "approvalUrl": "'.$approval_url.'",
        "placeholder": "ppplus",
        "mode": "sandbox",
        "country": "DE"
    });
</script>
```

documentation says **"Prior to rendering the payment wall a payment resource must be created. The
corresponding API call is “create payment”. "**

and is not clear to me how do I get an `$approval_url`. How do I create a payment over paypal api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create a payment** (Endpoint: POST /v1/payments/payment)

Depending on the *payment_method* and the *funding_instrument*, you can use a number of payment resources. For PayPal PLUS the only valid payment resource is PayPal account payments. In the response PayPal returns a payment object along with the state of the payment and sale. The response includes a ***payment ID*** that uniquely identifies the transaction. Also included is an *approval_url* that is required to render the PayPal PLUS payment wall. Since Create Payment is called prior to the actual payment selection you may want to exclude user specific data. The payment resource can be updated with this data at a later stage.

For more information check the documentation (Page Number 8)
[DE Integration Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/de_DE/downloads/PayPal-PLUS-IntegrationGuide.pdf)

Comment: thanks between I found out that I have to call ` /v1/payments/payment` but as it in docs stays I should get back the approvalUrl in related_resources but in my case is empty